# How can I make a WinPE application in visual studio with c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, winpe

I am making a command line application in C++ for [WinPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro), which I am booting from my flash drive. I made a C++ console application in [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) (2019), and I put the app on another partition of the flash drive. I tried to run the application in WinPE, but it said that the application was not compatible with WinPE. I tried deciphering [this page by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-apps) (I couldn't find anything on other sites), and I tried some of the things it says, but it just wasn't working. I don't think I fully understand some of the things on that page, but maybe you do.

Comment: Did you match the 64bit / 32bit WinPE with your application?

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, I tried both versions

Comment: The net/net of it is that there's an immense amount of stuff not in winpe. So if you're doing c++, you have to not use atl or mfc...or the .net clr. Threading model is also restricted. There are, however, some packages you can deploy to winpe...and get back "some" of the stuff you might want to use. Honestly, you can get further faster if you deploy clr support and do your app in c#. You _might_ be able to do a clr app in c++, but I've never met anyone who tried it and lived to tell.